# How to fetch data from another javascript file

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

I am trying to use the fetch API and async await to fetch an array in another file and use it in a separate js file.

For example:

data.js
app.js

I am working within app.js and would like to use the data (in an array) from data.js

data.js looks like this:

```js
//data.js
const data = ['steve','jim','julie']
```

```js
//app.js
const res = fetch('./data.js')
const data = res.data
```

I seem to be unable to read the data variable from data.js into app.js.

Comment: `fetch()` doesn't return the file contents, it returns a promise. You need to read a fetch tutorial to learn how to get the contents. Once you get that, you can use `eval()` to execute it.

Comment: Why not use a JSON file instead of JS?

Comment: @Barmar I am only supposed to use a js file

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to do javascript import

```
// module "my-module.js"

export default function cube(x) {
  return x * x * x;
}


// another file.js

import cube from './my-module.js'
console.log(cube(3)); // 27
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Comment: I am not trying to import a function. I am trying to import an array. The data.js file exports the array

Comment: You can import any type of variable. @TylerMorales

Comment: as @Barmar said you can also import array with the same syntax

Answer (score 0):

To export the data, use export:

```
export const data = ['steve','jim','julie'];
```

then import it in your main file and display it:

```
const your_export = require('./modules');
let {  data } = your_export
console.log(data)
```

You can read more about it [here](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-are-module-exports-in-javascript)